# Cookie not sent in API calls

Tags: angular, web, cookies, frontend, cross-domain

We have a web application web.companyname.com which makes API calls to a bunch of microservices service1.companyname.com, service2.companyname.com etc.

The application is in our corporate network behind a proxy and the proxy authenticates the users and assigns the cookie

Set-Cookie: NSC_TMAS=547857834758478454545;Secure;Path=/;Domain=companyname.com

**The problem** : The application cannot send cookie in API calls to endpoints service1.companyname.com, service2.companyname.com etc. , alought it can read it - console.log(document.cookie) shows the required cookie.

When the same application is opened with chrome withour security , the cookie is sent without any problem.

What could be the reason?

Comment: `Domain=companyname.com` <-- cookie is restricted to those. `service1.companyname.com` is another domain.

Comment: @MarkusZeller that should not be the case any more in modern browsers. The convention that the domain name needs to start with a dot to include subdomains, has been dropped a while ago. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Domain_attribute: _“If `Domain` is specified, then subdomains are always included. […] For example, if `Domain=mozilla.org` is set, then cookies are available on subdomains like `developer.mozilla.org`.”_

Comment: _“which makes API calls”_ - how? Details, please.